# Can an endogenous variable be independent?

Tags: statistics

An article I read states that "endogenous variables can be both dependent and independent variables"

I don't get it. An n endogenous variable is determined within the model. It is explained by the model, and depends on other variables. So, if it depends, how can it be independent?

To provide context:

"Path analysis is an advanced statistical technique for examination of dependent and independent variables to reveal the relative effects of each variable on the other variables in the model. Path analysis starts with a theory bound approach revealed with the construction of an explicitly formulated structural model
(path diagram) that provides a pictorial representation of relationships among variables. In path models, arrows indicate the hypothesized paths and the direction of influences between two types of variables: endogenous and exogenous. Exogenous variables have no arrows toward them from other variables in the model and the value of the exogenous variable is not explained by the other variables. In contrast, an endogenous variable has several arrows
coming toward it and its value is explained by one or more of the other variables. Moreover, endogenous variables can be both dependent and independent variables"

Comment: Just because it is explained by the model does not mean it depends on the other variables. You seem to have that false assumption.  Edit : it seems indeed the question is more complicated then I thought . Seemingly diffirent definitions of endogenous variable between stats and economics

Comment: I prefer language 'predictor' and 'predicted' because the meaning is clear. It seems definitions of 'dependent', 'independent', 'exogenous', etc. can shift slightly depending on author and field of application. Be sure to check definitions given in the book you're using.

Comment: I took it to mean that if an arrow is pointing to a variable from other variables, it's endogeneous, and also dependent on the parent variable (assuming no weird pathological example). That's all expected. However, if that variable then has an arrow towards another one, it is an "independent" variable for that last endogeneous variable.

For example the model $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$, $Y$ and $Z$ are both endogeneous, but $Z$ is only dependent and $Y$ is both?

I may be misunderstanding the question.